# best java approach for stream filtering in XML?

Tags: java, xml

I want to take an XML file as input and output the same XML except for some search/replace actions for attributes and text, based on matching certain node characteristics.

**What's the best general approach for this, and are there tutorials somewhere?**

DOM is out since I can't guarantee being able to keep the whole thing in memory.

I don't mind using SAX or StAX, except that I want the default behavior to be a pass-through no-op filter; I did something similar with StAX once and it was a pain, didn't work with namespaces, and I was never sure if I had included all the cases I needed to handle.

I think XSLT won't work (but am not sure), because it's declarative and I need to do some procedural calculations when figuring out what text/attributes to emit on the output.

(contrived example:

Suppose I was looking for all nodes with XPath of `/group/item/@number` and wanted to evaluate the `number` attribute as an integer, factor it using a method `public List<Integer> factorize(int i)`, convert the list of factors to a space-delimited string, and add an attribute `factors` to the corresponding `/group/item` node?

input:

```
<group name="beatles"><item name="paul" number="64"></group>
<group name="rolling stones"><item name="mick" number="19"></group>
<group name="who"><item name="roger" number="515"></group>
```

expected output:

```
<group name="beatles"><item name="paul" number="64" factors="2 2 2 2 2 2"></group>
<group name="rolling stones"><item name="mick" number="19" factors="19"></group>
<group name="who"><item name="roger" number="515" factors="103 5"></group>
```

)

**Update:** I got the StAX XMLEventReader/Writer method working easily, but it doesn't preserve certain formatting quirks that are important in my application. (I guess the program that saves/loads XML doesn't honor valid XML files. >:( argh.) Is there a way to process XML that minimizes textual differences between input and output? (at least when it comes to character data.)

Answer (score 3):

XSLT seems like an appropriate model for what you are doing. Look into using XSLT with procedural extensions.

If you really can't keep the whole document in memory, [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.2/sourcedocs/serial.html) is your only XSLT choice. It's likely that whatever calculations you need to do can be done in XSLT -- but if not, it's not too hard to write your own [extension functions](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.2/extensibility/intro.html).

Answer (score 2):

I find [Apache Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) a big help for rules-based parsing of XML.

**Update:** If it's filtering and output that you're concerned with, review this set of articles on Developerworks which is concerned with the same issues. Of particular relevance are parts [2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipbigdoc2.html), [3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipbigdoc3.html) and [4](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipbigdoc4.html). The summary: Use SAX, XMLFilter and XMLWriter.

While I suppose this is technically a good fit for XSLT, I've always found it hard to debug for complex transformations. YMMV :-)

**Further Update:** XMLWriter is available from [here](http://www.megginson.com/downloads/). I don't know what your particular difficulty with SAX is. I created a file `groups.xml` containing:

```
<groups>
<group name="beatles"><item name="paul" number="64"/></group>
<group name="rolling stones"><item name="mick" number="19"/></group>
<group name="who"><item name="roger" number="515"/></group>
</groups>
```

Note that I had to make some changes to make it well-formed XML. Then, I knocked up this simple [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) script, `groups.py`, to illustrate how to solve your problem:

```
import java.io
import org.xml.sax.helpers
import sys

sys.path.append("xml-writer.jar")
import com.megginson.sax

def get_factors(n):
    return "factors for %s" % n

class MyFilter(org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl):
    def startElement(self, uri, localName, qName, attrs):
        if qName == "item":
            newAttrs = org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl(attrs)
            n = attrs.length
            for i in range(n):
                name = attrs.getLocalName(i)
                if name == "number":
                    newAttrs.addAttribute("", "factors", "factors",
                                          "CDATA",
                                          get_factors(attrs.getValue(i)))
            attrs = newAttrs
        #call superclass method...
        org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(self, uri, localName,
                                                       qName, attrs)

source = org.xml.sax.InputSource(java.io.FileInputStream("groups.xml"))
reader = org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()
filter = MyFilter(reader)
writer = com.megginson.sax.XMLWriter(filter,
                                     java.io.FileWriter("output.xml"))
writer.parse(source)
```

Obviously, I've mocked up the factor finding function as your example was, I believe, purely illustrative. The script reads `groups.xml`, applies a filter, and outputs to `output.xml`. Let's run it:

```
$ jython groups.py
$ cat output.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

<groups>
<group name="beatles"><item name="paul" number="64" factors="factors for 64"></item></group>
<group name="rolling stones"><item name="mick" number="19" factors="factors for 19"></item></group>
<group name="who"><item name="roger" number="515" factors="factors for 515"></item></group>
</groups>
```

Job done? Of course, you'll need to transcribe this code to Java.

Comment: The parsing of what I want to do isn't hard. But I need to emit output that is essentially the same as my input, with intentional differences only

Comment: @Jason S that sounds an awful lot like XSLT's domain

Comment: @Vinay: Now I remember why I hate SAX: I can never get the damn thing working. XMLWriter does not seem to be a recognized class, and as simple as XMLFilter sounds I can't seem to figure out how to create something that outputs XML.

Answer (score 1):

StAX should work well for you. Piping input to output is super easy; you just write the XMLEvent you get from the XMLEventReader to the XMLEventWriter.

```
XMLEventFactory EVT_FACTORY;
XMLEventReader reader;
XMLEventWriter writer;

QName numberQName = new QName("number");
QName factorsQName = new QName("factors");
while(reader.hasNext()) {
  XMLEvent e = reader.nextEvent();
  if(e.isAttribute() && ((Attribute)e).getName().equals(numberQName)) {
     String v = ((Attribute)e).getValue();
     String factors = factorize(Integer.parseInt(v));
     XMLEvent factorsAttr = EVT_FACTORY.createAttribute(factorsQName, factors);
     writer.add(factorsAttr);
  }
  // pass through
  writers.add(e);
}
```

Comment: asAttribute doesn't seem to exist, but this gives me some food for thought. thanks.

Comment: ...and it looks like XMLEvent returned from nextEvent() won't ever be an attribute directly, but rather a start document / start element / characters / end doc/element.

Comment: Unfortunately XMLEventReader / Writer doesn't preserve formatting quirks. drat.

Comment: I doubt that there's any XML library that will preserve "formatting quirks", if you're referring to things that XML spec deems insignificant.